# Spring 4.x where to put application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

We are using a Spring 4.x application that using annotation configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myproject"})
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
```

Now when I run my application it is (quite rightly as the file is outside the app) telling me:

```
class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
```

So I want to move the `application.properties` file to classpath, but I don't know what that is for Spring/this app. Searching for this all I can find is XML configuration and/or Spring Boot - both we are not using. We have a not so conventional directory structure laos so no `resources` directory - I was hoping I could configure this to look somewhere else. Is there a default location for classpath? Otherwise, how do I define where to put/find this properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/wherever/whatever</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

Maven will happily put anything in this directory into our built classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally put it in "src\main\resources" directory. However when you package it into a war file, then you can check if it's in there by unzipping the war file. This way you can make sure that your properties file was inserted during the build.You should find it inside "WEB-INF\classes"